# How To Find RegEx .Net in the midle of string?

Tags: .net, regex

I have problem when find regex .Net please take a look at the following string:

```
http://www.domain.com/some-urls-sample.html
```

from that string I only need grab `www.domain.com` then removed the string before (`http://`) and after (`/some-urls-sample.html`).

My question is: how or what regex code to find parameter before and after regex we want to?

Comment: use `System.Uri`, not a regex.

Comment: why must you use a regex?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^http://([^/]+)
```

The string you want is in group 1.

Comment: almost but not exactly  that regex include http:// but I only need www.domain.com  please see attachment http://oi58.tinypic.com/2eehmk0.jpg

Comment: and also with or without www.

Comment: @LiemKevin: Sorry, I don't get you. This regex extract the domain in group 1, isn't that what you want? Please, edit your question and add some sample inputs and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

hi here is my sample regex I created

```
[^http://.][a-z0-9\.]+[^a-z.-]
```

but unfortunately it's not exactly that I want.. because result is **www.domain.com**/ not **www.domain.com**